# Is there is a simple way to have pd.plot or plt.plot() use the time of day for the y axis?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a table of sunrise and sunset times.  I would like to plot the years on the x-axis and the time of day on the y axis. However, when just plugging in the dataframe, I get floats, unrelated to time of day, on the y axis.

I have tried various solutions, which I can't seem to make work. Including using subplots with the following:

```
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(HourLocator())
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
```

Here is the code:

```
import sunriset

lat = 34.0522
long = -118.2437
local_tz = -8

number_of_years = 10
start_date = datetime.date(2010,1,1)

df = sunriset.to_pandas(start_date, lat, long, local_tz, number_of_years)

sunrise_set = df[['Sunrise', 'Sunset', 'Sunlight Duration (minutes)']]
sunrise_set.index = pd.to_datetime(sunrise_set.index)

plt.plot(sunrise_set['Sunrise'])
plt.show()
```

I would like for this to have the time in the y axis not the floats.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out.  The format of the pandas columns needed to be converted to to datetime, even though they show up as datetime when doing df.describe()

```
sunrise_set['Sunrise'] = pd.to_datetime(sunrise_set['Sunrise'])
sunrise_set['Sunrise'] = [time.time() for time in sunrise_set['Sunrise']]
sunrise_set['Sunset'] = pd.to_datetime(sunrise_set['Sunset'])
sunrise_set['Sunset'] = [time.time() for time in sunrise_set['Sunset']]
```